# Override Host in HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient but it has problems with DNS resolve (it is using the sync method for this) So I use another lib for doing DNS queries and now I'm tryging to get custom urls by IP but I need to replace Host header. For example I have url http://fb.com but I need to get http://1.1.1.1 with Host set to fb.com I've tryied:

```
_req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, newUri.ToString());
_req.Headers.Host = uri.Host;
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;
```

but this doesn't work. Is there any way to set own Host header like in HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's work. The problem was with Fiddler which override Host header based on url. When Fiddler is off everything is going fine.

Comment: my god... I always used Fiddler to test my api calls... never tought about it... You save me a lot of time...