# HttpClient is ignoring the `www.` part of the Request URI

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send a `GET` request with `HttpClient`:

```
public static HttpClient Client { get
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip };
    var http = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com/") };
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("*/*");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.TryParseAdd("en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.TryParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "example.com";
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "600");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
    ServicePointManager
        .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    return http;
}
...
using (var client = HttpHelper.Client)
using (var res = await client.GetAsync("api/stuff/filter?order=" + order + "&page=" + page))
    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnimeResponse>(json);
        return response;
    }
```

Unfortunately this sends a request without the `www.` part and results in `301` status code as well as many, many failed redirects to the same address (without the `www.` part).

How can I fix this?

Edit: When I re-send the request with Fiddler it also returns 301, but the n it redirects correctly to `wwww.`. The `HttpClient` doesn't, and just redirects to the same www-less URI.

Comment: Where are you trying to request data from - `https://www.example.com/`? Then why are you setting the request default hostname to `masterani.me`, I wonder …?

Comment: What makes you believe it is sending the request without `www`? Are you running Fiddler?

Comment: What site in your IE browser are allowed and blocked?  Can you get to site using your IE?

Comment: @jdweng Yes I can.

Comment: @mjwills I'm checking with Fiddler.

Comment: If you stop using Fiddler, does it work? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371487/34092 .

Comment: When you get to site with IE does it show the WWW.  The site may be redirecting your.  With fiddler check if the header is http 1.0 or http 1.1

Comment: @mjwills nope, same thing without Fiddler.

Comment: @jdweng when I open the url without www in IE it redirects correctly to www. It's HTTP 1.1

Comment: What happens if you comment out this line `http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "example.com";`?

Comment: @mjwills then it starts working. Thanks, I didn't think that would affect it.

Comment: HttpClient does *not* ignore `www.`. 301s are generated by the *server*. Either there's a problem with the server, or it doesn't like the headers you send, eg why set `Host`? Have you tried just calling the server without setting any headers?

Comment: @CBroe pointed you in that direction above.

Comment: Compare the fiddler results with IE against the results with your application.  Compare the headers for differences.