# How to change hostname (host http header) with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

Quick question: is there a way to change the host name that is sent by HttpClient while maintaining the destination url? For instance, in Postman I can create a new custom request that targets site a.com with the host http header set to b.com. I've tried using the following code to achieve that with HttpClient:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
              {
                  ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender,
                                                               cert,
                                                               chain,
                                                               sslPolicyErrors) =>true
              };
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "b.com";

try
{
    var uri =
        "https:a.com/someurl/more";
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    Console.Write(response.Substring(0, 100));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

As it's been pointed out in the comments, I was being redirected to the wrong url becuase Fiddler was active. Now, I must be doing something wrong because the request sent from postman with the custom header does return the correct HTML and the one using HttpClient is giving me a 503.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Fiddler perhaps? [Fiddler will overwrite the HOST header based on the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303372/override-host-in-httpclient)

Comment: Why is host and URL different?  The host is usually the beginning of the URL.  The server may be doing a redirect.

Comment: Indeed, why try to override HOST at all? Even the possible duplicate overrides the HOST header for the wrong reason. There's nothing wrong with DNS resolution. It's not even performed by HttpClient, it's performed by the OS. Most likely, the code used a singleton HttpClient and the DNS mapping changed. That's why HttpClientFactory is used to recycle sockets periodically

Comment: Yes, I'musing Fiddler and it changed the host. The objetive is to do this through code: https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/custom-ssl-configurations/

Comment: Ok, everything  is working out. I've turned off/on link branding and everything started working...